# MS access - Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error while sending email

Tags: ms-access

I have a code that is used to send emails using outlook from access. This code is throwing "Application-Defined or objected-Defined" error when the code is reaching `.Recipient.Add` line. This code works totally fine in my system but not in my colleague system. I have checked libraries and everything match but still the error is coming.

```
Private Sub Toggle182_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_Toggle182_Click
    
    Dim BaCode As String
    Dim lst As Control
    Set lst = Me.name
    Dim BillingMnth As String
    BillingMnth = Format(Me.Billing_Month, "mmm")
    Dim oItem As Variant
    Dim iCount As Integer
    
    Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim sqry As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    If lst.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each oItem In lst.ItemsSelected
            BaCode = lst.Column(0, oItem)
            fileName = "My local path"
            fileName = fileName & name & BillingMnth & ".xlsx"
            sqry = "Select Distribution_List from details where name='" & name & "';"
            Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqry)
    
            Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            With oEmail
                rs.MoveFirst
                While Not rs.EOF
                    .Recipients.Add rs.Fields("Distribution_List")
                    rs.MoveNext
                Wend
    
                .Subject = "RTB"
                .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Dear User <br><br> Please find the attached file. <br><br> Kindly do let us know in case of any concerns. <br> <br><br>Kind Regards, <br>company <br> </BODY></HTML>"
                .Attachments.Add fileName
                .Save
                .Send
            End With
            iCount = iCount + 1
        Next oItem
        MsgBox "Email successfully sent!", vbInformation, "EMAIL STATUS"
    Else
        MsgBox "Please slect the name"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Err_Toggle182_Click:
    'MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible that rs.Fields("Distribution_List") is null?
Try nz(rs.Fields("Distribution_List"),"") and see if it works.

Comment: It is not null, in fact I have tried to hard the email address as .Recipients.Add("myemail@xyz.com").
This code perfectly works for me.  but it is throwing error only for colleagues. Almost checked all the configuration and everything is same

Comment: When i used .To ="myemail.xyz.com", it passed through however now .Send is not working

Comment: seems due to organization policy automatic send email functionality is not working! I'm trying to use sendkeys command here that would pass ctrl+enter command on the drafted email